# C - (mathematical) integration with GSL causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, math, mex, gsl

So I'm trying to do an integration for an option model in C. The function gets called from Matlab and is compiled as a mex file.
the function hestonIntegrand1 does return a value when called outside the gsl_integration_qaigu, so the error must be happening inside this integration function. any ideas what's wrong? is it just a mathematical problem?

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "complex.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

#define MAX_WORKSPACE_SIZE 1000


struct hestonIntegrandParams 
{
    double _Complex K;
    //double X;
    double St;
    double tau;
    double theta;
    double kappa;
    double sigmaV;
    double sigma;
    double rho;
    double gamma;
    double r;
};


double hestonIntegrand1 (double _Complex phi, void * p) {

    /*
     double _Complex im = 0.0f + 1.0f * _Complex_I ;
     double _Complex re = 1.0f + 0.0f * _Complex_I ;
     */

    struct hestonIntegrandParams * params = (struct hestonIntegrandParams *)p;

    double _Complex K = (params->K);
    //double X = (params->X);
    double St = (params->St);
    double tau = (params->tau);
    double theta = (params->theta);
    double kappa = (params->kappa);
    double sigmaV = (params->sigmaV);
    double sigma = (params->sigma);
    double rho = (params->rho);
    double gamma = (params->gamma);
    double r = (params->r);

    double x = log (St);



    double u1 = 0.5f;

    //double b1 = kappa+lambda-rho*sigma;

    // under EMQ lambda falls out
    double b1 = kappa-rho*sigma;

    double _Complex i = 0.0f + 1.0f * _Complex_I;

    double _Complex d1 = sqrt(pow((rho*sigma*phi*i-b1),2) - (sigma*sigma)*(2*u1*phi*i-phi*phi) );

    double _Complex g1 = (b1-rho*sigma*phi*i+d1) / (b1-rho*sigma*phi*i-d1);

    double _Complex D1 = (b1-rho*sigma*phi*i+d1)/(sigma*sigma) * ((1.0f-exp(d1*tau))/(1.0f-g1*exp(d1*tau)));

    double _Complex C1 = r*phi*i*tau + (kappa*theta/(sigma*sigma))* (
                                                                     (b1-rho*sigma*phi*i+d1)*theta -
                                                                     2 - log( (1- g1*exp(d1*theta) ) / (1-g1) )
                                                                     );


    double _Complex f1 = exp(C1 + D1*sigmaV + i*phi*x);

    double _Complex Re = 1.0f + 0.0f * _Complex_I;

    double _Complex integrand = Re*(exp(-i*phi*log(K))*f1)/(i*phi);

    // returning just the real part
    return (creal(integrand));

}

// -callHestoncf(u, X, v, r, q, v0, vT, rho, k, sigma, implVol )
double hestonCallOption ( double St, double K,
                         double tau, double r, double theta, double kappa, double sigma, double sigmaV,
                         double rho, double gamma) {

    gsl_integration_workspace *work_ptr =
    gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (MAX_WORKSPACE_SIZE);
    gsl_integration_workspace *work_ptr2 =
    gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (MAX_WORKSPACE_SIZE);

    double lower_limit = 0.0f;  /* start integral from 1 (to infinity) */
    double abs_error = 1.0e-8;  /* to avoid round-off problems */
    double rel_error = 1.0e-8;  /* the result will usually be much better */
    /* the result from the integration
     and  the estimated errors from the integration
     */
    double result1, result2, error1, error2;

    double alpha = 2.0;
    double expected = -0.16442310483055015762;  /* known answer */

    gsl_function F1;
    gsl_function F2;

    struct hestonIntegrandParams params = {
        K, St, tau, theta, kappa, sigmaV, sigma, rho, gamma, r
    };

    F1.function = &hestonIntegrand1;
    F1.params = &params;
    F2.function = &hestonIntegrand2;
    F2.params = &params;

    mexWarnMsgTxt("YOLO");


    gsl_integration_qagiu (&F1, lower_limit,
                           abs_error, rel_error, MAX_WORKSPACE_SIZE, work_ptr, &result1,
                           &error1);

    gsl_integration_qagiu (&F2, lower_limit,
                           abs_error, rel_error, MAX_WORKSPACE_SIZE, work_ptr2, &result2,
                           &error2);

    mexWarnMsgTxt("YOLO2");

    gsl_integration_workspace_free (work_ptr);
    gsl_integration_workspace_free (work_ptr2);
    // df = discount factor
    double df = exp(-r*tau);

    //StP1 ? KP(t, T)P2
    double price = St*result1-K*df*result2;
    //double price = hestonIntegrand1(1, &params);
    //double price = 2.0f;
    return price;
}


/* the gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *y,*z;
    double  x;
    mwSize mrows,ncols;

    /*  check for proper number of arguments */
    /* NOTE: You do not need an else statement when using mexErrMsgTxt
     within an if statement, because it will never get to the else
     statement if mexErrMsgTxt is executed. (mexErrMsgTxt breaks you out of
     the MEX-file) */
    char buf[256];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "11 inputs required, but only %i provided", nrhs);

    if(nrhs!=1)
        mexErrMsgTxt(buf);
    if(nlhs!=1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("1 output required.");

    /* check to make sure the first input argument is a scalar */
    /*
     if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) ||
     mxGetN(prhs[0])*mxGetM(prhs[0])!=1 ) {
     mexErrMsgTxt("Input x must be a scalar.");
     }
     */



    /*  set the output pointer to the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mrows,ncols, mxREAL);

    /*  create a C pointer to a copy of the output matrix */
    //z = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    mxArray *xData;
    double *xValues, *outArray;

    //Copy input pointer x
    xData = prhs[0];
    xValues = mxGetPr(xData);

    double price = hestonCallOption ( xValues[0] , xValues[1], xValues[2] ,
                                     xValues[3], xValues[4], xValues[5], xValues[6], xValues[7],
                                     xValues[8], xValues[9] );    

    //Allocate memory and assign output pointer
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL); //mxReal is our data-type
    outArray = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    outArray[0] = price;
    /*  call the C subroutine */
    //xtimesy(x,y,z,mrows,ncols);

}
```

Comment: Was any memory allocated for `void * p` in `double hestonIntegrand1`?

Comment: I believe so. Isn't that happening here: `struct hestonIntegrandParams * params = (struct hestonIntegrandParams *)p;`?

Comment: That statement doesn't allocate anything (except maybe a pointer).  It says "Assume `p` points at a `struct hestonIntegrandParams`; call that `*params`."

Comment: Setup of `params` doesn't look like it is unitialized. The value established as  F1 and F2 `params` member is a local variable `struct hestonIntegrandParams params` within `hestonCallOption ()`. Something else is off, or that is not setup correctly (sry, I'm not familiar with the API).

Comment: I basically stuck to this example: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-integration-examples.html

Comment: What is `hestonIntegrand2`?

Comment: hestonIntegrand2 has a slight modification which is required for the pricing model. I left it out because the error already happens within the first integration and the function is identical with except for three values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hestonIntegrand1` (and I believe `hestonIntegrand2`) functions take a complex number as the first parameter, but `gsl_function` only allows a function that takes a `double`. If you enabled the highest warning level, you should have seen an incompatible pointer assignment.

You can work around this limitation by creating separate functions for each component of the complex function, and integrating twice, once for the real component, and once for the imaginary component. Combining the results together should give you your complex result.

Comment: thanks! At first I was surprised that this resulted in a segfault. But after running a small comparison: `sizeof (double) = 8, sizeof(complex double) = 16`  this makes perfect sense.